# What are the differences between 1 large segment in APC vs many smaller segments?

Tags: apc

Are there any differences between these 2 examples:

- 1 Shared Memory Segment @ 256MB
- 4 Shared Memory Segments @ 64MB

Do multiple segments make it easier for APC to clean up stale entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, some systems (including most BSD variants) have very low limits on the size of a shared memory segment, so to give APC access to more memory, because you can't increase the size of each segment, you have to increase the number of segments.

Seems like there should be just 1 setting where you say "Give APC this much memory" and it automatically figures out what to do based on your system configuration... but that'd require inspecting your configurations etc, so they just leave it up to you to configure it properly :)

Because it seems there are only 2 settings to account for the fact that some systems are gimpy when it comes to the size it allows, I would go for 1 big segment whenever possible.

Doesn't seem like it should affect performance one way or the other, though.

Comment: I see...so it's more of a way to get around system limitations than the way APC will operate? Makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 3):

APC does not like multiple segments anymore actually.

The default MMAP mode completely ignores that setting and uses a single segment which is far faster.

So unless you're on an old BSD box, it uses a single segment by default & avoids maintaining 4 locks for the same memory instead of 1.